# Bug with transform: scale, overflow: hidden and border-radius in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a strange problem in Firefox. I've created an css animation where I scale down my `div#flying_object`, move it and in the end I scale it back to original size. My `div.flying_object_container` has `border-radius: 50%;` and `overflow: hidden`. So if the flying object overflows the parent div it should be hidden. In Firefox the flying object is sometimes visible outside of the parent div. You have to hover the element to see the animation.

This is what sometimes happens in my animation:

[image]

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upLm0scq/8/).

It works in Chrome, Opera, IE11, Safari(with a bugfix) but not in Firefox.

Hope someone can help me. :)

Comment: I don't know about how to fix this bug but you can use `font-size` instead of `scale` it is a solution !

Comment: tried it in firefox, and sometimes it overflows . try to add overflow:hidden to other elements . like to the `svg` element. maybe that will do the trick

Comment: `overflow: hidden` to other elements sadly does not work. Changing the background-size and the position would be also a workaround but I would like to see a solution with `transform: scale()`.

Comment: @Huelfe am not able to reproduce it in my Firefox.

Comment: You are right. Can't reproduce it as well in firefox 55.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was fixed in [Firefox 50](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/50.0/releasenotes/).

```
Fixed rendering of dashed and dotted borders with rounded corners (border-radius)
```

Tested versions `49`, `49.0.2` and `50`.